# Martingale property and conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis

We consider a cadlag stochastic process $(X_r)_r$ with non-decreasing sample paths and $X_0=0.$ Let $Y_r:=X_r-r.$ We suppose that $(Y_r)_r,(Y^2_r-r)_r,$ and $(Y_r^3-3rY_r-r)_r$ are martingales relative to the canonical filtration of $(\mathcal{F}_r)_r$ of $(X_r)_r.$

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function of class $C^{\infty}$ with bounded derivatives.

Find, for $r \leq u,$ the expression of $E[f(X_u)|\mathcal{F}_r]$ in term of the derivatives of $f.$

So how could we find an expression for $E[f(X_u)|\mathcal{F}_r]$?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What are your thoughts on how to find that expression?

Comment: I think Ito's formula could be helpful, but I do not know how use it with the 3 above martingales

Comment: Applying Itô directly gives some sort of result, but the problem is in the use of these martingales. Something tells me that $Y$ is in fact a brownian motion. Specially the $(Y_t^3-3tY_t-t)_t$ part.

Comment: @Hamdiken I would agree if $Y$ were continuous, but I don't think it's possible for $Y$ to be a Brownian motion.  Since $X$ is non-decreasing, we have $Y_r = X_r-r \ge X_0-r = -r$, so $Y_r$ is bounded from below and in particular cannot be normally distributed.

Comment: @user6247850 Good point, I agree.

Comment: @user6247850 What do you think about the Martingale representation theorem ?

Comment: @Hamdiken The martingale representation theorem I'm familiar with says we can rewrite processes $M_t$ which are martingales with respect to the filtration generated by a Brownian motion $B_t$ as $M_t = M_0 + \int_0^t Z_s dB_s$ for some process $Z$, but I don't think that would be too helpful here.  Is there another one you are referring to?

Comment: @user6247850 I thought about it for a moment then I figured it won't help.

Comment: A Poisson process verifies the assumptions

Comment: By Lévy's characterization theorem, $Y_{r}$ has quadratic variation $r$ if and only if $Y$ is a Brownian motion. Are you sure all the assumptions are correct?